# Visual Basic - Date Format in ReadOnly Property

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need your help. I am trying to format the date but i cant seem to do that. Please see my current code below

```
Private v_DateOfBirth As Date
Public ReadOnly Property DateOfBirth() As Date
Get
   Return v_DateOfBirth.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
End Get
End Property
```

**Desired output:** January 1, 2019

**Current output:** 2019-01-01

Comment: You've declared `DateOfBirth() As Date`. Your getter can't return string for a date property that you've declared as being of type `Date`. If you want it to return a string, then declare the property as a string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a string value.

```
Private v_DateOfBirth As Date
Public ReadOnly Property DateOfBirth() As String
    Get
        Return v_DateOfBirth.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
    End Get
End Property
```